# Laravel layout issue

Tags: layout, laravel, controller, render

Hi i'm new in Laravel and my question may sound stupid, but i cant find how to render controller from layout.

- I want to implement this: in my layout i have @yield content where to be renderen my main content. I want above to render header view and under content - footer view, but from layout. I dont want to include them in every view i create, so i want to render header and footer controllers direct from layout or something similar.
- I came from symfony and there is render controller function in twig,
  but here i cant find best solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are supposed to represent resources, not pages or elements.

It would help if we knew what kind of things you wanted to control in your header and footer, but I can provide some common examples:

- Things like logo or site name can be hardcoded into the html or set in config values
- Logged in users should be handled by your Authentication controller and stored in a session
- A menu is normally hardcoded or database driven.

Comment: In symfony when you render controller that mean from view source invoke some method in controller and receive a response which in my case is view.
I'm using a big headers with a lot of information (even menu which is not hardcoded but with a administration module ), dynamic language module,dynamic links, and nothing hardcoded, so i want to invoke some method and render its response which is view in my case.